# How to get from Bremen airport arrivals to Bremen airport Departures quickly

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, connecting-flights

I made a booking via kiwi.com and my connecting flight from Bremen is 1h30 mins after I arrive in Bremen but it's a self transfer flight. So I have to collect my bags and go all the way through security etc.

From Bremen arrivals (where I collect my bags from the previous flight) what is the fastest way to get to the Bremen departures.

I don't want to miss my connecting flight

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bremen is a relatively small airport. After your arrival and baggage claim, you end up in the check in hall again, where you can drop off your luggage, and after that you take the stairs or elevator to the second floor where you find the security checks for departure.

You can find a map here (unfortunately the detailed map is only available on the german version): https://www.bremen-airport.com/service/orientierung/terminal-uebersicht/

Comment: The key on the detailed map is in German *and English*, so the fact it is only linked from the German page is not too bad.

Comment: Yes, but if you set the website language to english and navigate to that page, you don't see any maps at all.

Comment: I would just like to say it took us 18 minutes but the airport was pretty empty AFAIK it was the last flight out of Bremen. We left the baggage claim turned left and kept walking until we saw the check in counters. Then went upstairs and went through security then to gate 1b. Total took us 20 minutes. Amazing!!!!!! thank you. 

Also before dropping off the bags we accidentally went up to security with the bags because we didn't see the check-in counter) so we had to go back down with the trolley. This doesn't include time waiting for bags at the carousel which was like 15 mins !

Answer (score 4):

Bremen airport is small, and hence you should have no problems moving from arrivals to departure quickly.

I worked in Bremen for a few months, my office was close to the airport and from time to time I had lunch in the airport and that's just a small airport, you can go through the whole airport in only a few minutes.

Comment: But what kind of thing were you eating? How often?

Comment: I said eating but should have said "having lunch" instead, sorry english is not my native language and sometimes I still make some mistakes.